# How to insert data into Grid from record

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

I have record with three filed:

```
type
    TItem = record

    Item    : String;
    Quantity: SmallInt;
    Price   : Currency;
 end;
```

Also i have procedure for setting value into record:

```
function TForm1.SetItem(item:string;quan:SmallInt;price:Currency):TItem;
   var It :TItem; 
   begin
          It.Item :=item;
          It.Quantity:= quan;
          It.Price:=price;
         Result :=It;
   end;
```

Now, i need a procedure for inserting **record TItem** into **TStringGrid** or **TGrid** and i do not know how to do it. 
I also have three columns in my TStringGrid:

```
1. col_Item     :string;
2. col_Quantity :SmallInt;
3. col_Price    :Currency;
```

Every time when i call the procedure **SetItem** i need to insert into this three columns three filed from record:

Result should be like this:

```
ITEM      | Quantity  | Price   

Bread         1         1,5
Coca cola     1         3
Fanta         2         3
```

..and so on.

Comment: Your procedure SetItem() is useless. It creates a record of type TItem, fills it with values, and than throws it away without passing it back.

Comment: @GuidoG I have update question. It is mistake. Can u help me it  is clear what i need.

Comment: Firemonkey application?

Comment: @LURD yes it is.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the grid (`TGrid`) doesn't store data so you need to provide a data storage like f.ex. `TDataArr = array of TItem;`. When the grid needs data to show in a cell, it calls the `OnGetValue()` event:

```
procedure TForm4.Grid1GetValue(Sender: TObject; const Col, Row: Integer;
  var Value: TValue);
begin
  if Row > (Length(DataArr)-1) then exit;
  case Col of
    0: Value := DataArr[Row].Item;
    1: Value := DataArr[Row].Quantity;
    2: Value := DataArr[Row].Price;
  end;
end;
```

There is an implicit conversion to string for the disply in the grid.

When you edit data in the grid, the change triggers the `OnSetValue` event:

```
procedure TForm4.Grid1SetValue(Sender: TObject; const Col, Row: Integer;
  const Value: TValue);
begin
  if Row > (Length(DataArr)-1) then exit;
  case Col of
    0: DataArr[Row].Item := Value.AsString;
    1: DataArr[Row].Quantity := StrToInt(Value.AsString);
    2: DataArr[Row].Price := StrToCurr(Value.AsString);
  end;
end;
```

There doesn't seem to be an implicit conversion the other way, therefore the `StrToInt(Value.AsString)` and `StrToCurr(Value.AsString)`.